# netezza update statement taking very long time and high resources, need alternative

Tags: performance, time, sql-update, netezza

Full disclosure, I would consider myself still in the "beginner" stages of coding, so take it easy on me. I'm trying to update a very large table based on criteria from a separate table like this:

```
UPDATE table1 A
SET A.flag1 = 'RE' WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT B.CUSTOMER FROM ALL_CUST B 
WHERE A.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER 
AND B.DAY < (A.DAY - 365));
```

The problem is, this take a massive amount of memory and time to complete because of the size of each table (I think). I am looking for an alternative to the method I am trying to use. I have looked into batch running the statement, since it works acceptably well with smaller tables I work with, but I can't quite figure out how to make it work.

If needed, here are the other tables being used to create the update:

```
CREATE table table1 AS
SELECT CUSTOMER,
DAY,
'NW' AS FLAG1,
'NW' AS flag2
FROM database
WHERE CUSTOMER > -1
and othercriteria 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER,
Day;

CREATE table all_cust AS
SELECT CUSTOMER,
DAY,
FROM database
WHERE CUSTOMER > -1
and othercriteria 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER,
Day;
```

Comment: How many rows are in TABLE1 and ALL_CUST , and what are the distribution columns (if any) for those tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to add a 'distribute on (customer)' statement to the end of each of my base tables. This prevented the inefficiency of the customer being randomly housed across our disks and changed the update statement from hours to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Updates can be slow in `Netezza` especially as complexity is added.  I sometimes find it faster to move the change records to a temp table, delete the records I want to replace, & finally move the records back in from the temp table.  That being said.  I think the following changes will speed up the update you are trying to run.

```
UPDATE table1
SET flag1 = 'RE'
where rowid in
(SELECT distinct A.rowid
FROM ALL_CUST B inner join
 table1 A
on A.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER
AND B.DAY < (A.DAY - 365));
```

Comment: the join looks encouraging so far. a small table test dropped from 91 seconds to run to 15. trying on the big one now. thanks for the help

Comment: definitely better. about an hour now to run instead of 5. I still need to explore something else long term but I will figure that out when I have less of a time constraint.

Comment: I'm definitely confused by this answer. An update statement in Netezza *is* a delete + insert. How could doing the latter be faster?

Comment: I agree with @jeremytwfortune that there shouldn't be any performance difference.  In my experience I have seen consistent performance issues with correlated updates in `netezza`.  Known Issue [14573 12965](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.reln.doc/c_relnotes_known_issues.html) is just one example.